# UWP server application connect from same machine fails with 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, uwp, localhost, loopback

I'm developing an UWP app which needs to be the server for a win32 client application, which is not to be changed if possible. Now the problem is I can connect to my uwp server application if I connect to the hostname or IP address of my computer. In contrast if I use localhost or 127.0.0.1 I can't get a connection.

I'm running this command constantly to enable the connection without running it, it doesn't work at all. "CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -is -n=Packagename"

I also executed some tests, and found out that on the computer under company IT, it only works when using the IP address. Therefore with the identical setup on a computer which is not under the companies IT, it works as expected.

So I expect there's a problem with the way my machine is configured. 
We have an proxy for all outgoing connections. Another thing when I use a win32 server and client I have no problem to connect to localhost, so it seems that my machines dns configuration is in general right.

Do you have any ideas how to torubleshoot this, or what I can try to find out where my connection attempt is going. Maybe the UWP application is trying to connect over the proxy?

Comment: Have you tried some tool like Fiddler or WireShark? Monitor the request sent by the client.

Comment: Have you checked `Internet(Client & Server)` and Private `Networks(Client &Server)`capability?

Comment: For the "PackageName" did you use the app id?  I believe it's found at "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer".  As an aside, it's my understanding also you can do this if you're planning on side loading the app but you wouldn't be able to do this in the Windows Store if deploying it there.

Comment: @kennyzx I unfortunately didn't get wireshark to detect any of my interfaces, even when running as admin

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes these capabilities are enabled

Comment: @b.pell I used the thing vs2017 shows me in the Packaging tab. And it seems to do something because if I don't run the checknet tool nothing works so it seems to have some effect.